# I can't install Gedit after removing it

Tags: software-installation, nautilus, uninstall, gedit

I removed Gedit cause I wanted to install an older version. Now when I try to run it after installing it won't launch. And this **error messages** shows:

```
(gedit:9486): Glib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.nautilus.preferences' does not contain a key named 'enable-delete' 
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Comment: Probable reason is you have removed some core packages as well. Did you try 'sudo apt-get install -f' ?

Comment: How did you remove Gedit and how are you trying to reinstall it? I agree with Arijit on that you probably removed some core packages. Could you please run `sudo apt-get install -f ubuntu-desktop` and copy & paste its output into your question? Thanks.

Comment: And maybe even post a link if you followed a tutorial, and maybe if you sidetracked from the given procedure note that as well.

Comment: Try installing nautilus using this command.

"sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3"  ------
"sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nautilus"

Comment: 'Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version (1.361).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre-headless gnuplot-data gnuplot-x11
  java-common libaec0 libhdf5-10 liboctave3 libosmesa6 libplot2c2'

Comment: '  libpstoedit0c2a libqhull7 libqrupdate1 libqscintilla2-12v5
  libqscintilla2-l10n libqt4-opengl libsz2 libtext-unidecode-perl
  libxml-libxml-perl libxml-namespacesupport-perl libxml-sax-base-perl
  libxml-sax-expat-perl libxml-sax-perl octave-common octave-info
  openjdk-8-jre-headless pstoedit texinfo
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 127 not upgraded'

Comment: This is the output from running 'sudo apt-get install -f ubuntu-desktop'

Comment: it works :D installing nautilus worked perfectly thank you :D